# Finding roots in $Z_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

This must be a basic question but I will make it nonetheless.

If you a looking for roots of the polynomial $x^3-2x$, clearly the solutions are $0,\sqrt2,-\sqrt2$. But, if this polynomial is considered in $Z_3$, then $-2=1$, so the polynomial would be de same as $x^3+x$, that has roots $0,i,-i$.

Where is my argument failing?

Comment: What argument?  $x^3-2x\equiv x^3+x\pmod 3$ is true, and has no implications for the complex roots of either.

Comment: in $\Bbb{Z}_3$ there is no $i$. It has three elements $\{0,1,2\}$. So the only root is $x=0$.

Comment: @AnuragA But I want to extend the field so it has the roots of this polynomial

Comment: Modulo $3$, the square root of $-1$ is the square root of $2$. But $2$ has no square root in $\Bbb Z/3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you are working modulo $3$ then, in your language we have $i^2=-1\equiv 2$, so that modulo $3$ we have $i=\sqrt 2$ and there is no contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extend the to a field that has roots (as per your comment), then you need to consider the field $$\Bbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle x^2+1 \rangle=\{a\alpha +b \, | \, a,b \in \Bbb{Z}_3, \alpha^2+1 \equiv 0\}$$

Comment: I understand you, but my concern is that the polynomial $x^3-2x$ still has no roots in that field.And it´s ¨the same¨ polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial $x^3+x$ has the factorisation $x(x^2+1)$ over $\Bbb F_3$, and there is no element $a$ in $\Bbb F_3$ with $a^2=-1$, i.e., no such number like $i$ or $-i$. Hence $f(x)=x^3+x$ has only one root, namely $0$.